# How to design latex by eye and mouse only?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, wysiwyg

How can I drag and drop a latex document using my eye and mouse only?

In other words, I don't know **yet** what document design I'm looking for.

I'm an avid emacs and keyboard first user, however the forecast of spending days tinkering and compiling just to see how an image, width, border, text etc. looks with another millimeter, color etc. literally stops me from creation.

Offtopic: A first glimpse at
http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/ screenshots looked promising, alas a simple 'lorem ipsum' export returns a `There's no line here to end` error

Comment: The closest thing to WYSIWYG that is LaTeX-like is [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/). If you're creating a one-off document, then LaTeX may not be the ideal tool for you if you're relatively new to it. Its value comes from being able to create document classes and packages that separate formatting from content in ways that make formatting consistent for repeated use.  See also [Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/633)

Comment: What sort of documents are you thinking of: math texts, poetry, novels, theatrical scripts, compendiums of quotations, ... ? Basically LaTeX supports inclusions of graphics but not graphical document design. There are many classes/packages that provide design options.Try the `memdesign` paper (`> texdoc memdesign`) about book design and (`> texdoc memoir`) a general class with many design options. WARNING: I'm the original author of these. All the great typographers spent many hours refining their ideas.

Comment: @PeterWilson Good question. My inquiry is more general: I'm looking for a GUI that offers format design decoupled from any content decision. Similar to Adobe, Microsoft etc. Let's take the *anvil* in your documentation for example. How can I move, enlarge, exchange it immediately by simply trying everything out with the mouse (**not** by changing any code).

Comment: @AlanMunn I posted this question since I find myself every other couple of months needing a pdf that needs to be created by automation e.g. python. I haven't used MS Word since years, though in these rare occasions I miss it's WYSIWYG featurs to simply see what happens when I enlarge the font, border etc. by one or another pixel.

Comment: Even when it is possible to design a book cover in LaTeX, I use Illustrator for that work, for the same reasons you express.  I once tried InDesign for a whole book with no math but LaTeX produces a higher quality output.

Comment: @SimonDispa And how do you `convert` your layout from e.g. illustrator to LaTeX?

Comment: i do not.  The external cover is a separate file that goes for the printing press and has specs best accomplish with a layout program as illustrator. For the internal title page  I use `xcoffins` that work in a similar  way (no GUI) but separates content from design and use relative positions to set boxes on a page. If later I want to to put the cover in a pdf book, I add it, as first page, the  export of the front cover from illustrator.